# How do I make a Dropdown menu in AntD not display the three little dots next to it?

Tags: antd

If you look at the screenshot below, you can see what is being rendered:

[rendering of antd dropdown with three dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HT8r.png)

Code:

```
<Column title="Category" render={(text, record) => (
    <Dropdown placement="bottomLeft"
    overlay={
        <Menu>
            {productCategories.map(category => (
                <Menu.Item key={category.id}>
                    <a href="#" onClick={(event) => {event.preventDefault(); }}>
                        {category.name}
                    </a>
                </Menu.Item>
            ))}
        </Menu>
    }
    >
        <Dropdown.Button>
            Category // eventually this will be the selected category name
        </Dropdown.Button>
    </Dropdown>
)} />
```

There are two problems I'm experiencing:

1. The three dots are appearing... I don't know why
2. Whenever I hover my mouse over the three dots, an error occurs: `React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.` and the page just goes blank.

Helpful answers appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The first error occurs because you are using `Dropdown.Button` instead of `Button` inside `Dropdown`.
The second error occurs because `overlay` props must be passed to `Dropdown.Button`

To fix both errors you need to replace `Dropdown.Button` with `Button`

```
<Column title="Category" render={(text, record) => (
    <Dropdown placement="bottomLeft"
    overlay={
        <Menu>
            {productCategories.map(category => (
                <Menu.Item key={category.id}>
                    <a href="#" onClick={(event) => {event.preventDefault(); }}>
                        {category.name}
                    </a>
                </Menu.Item>
            ))}
        </Menu>
    }
    >
        <Button>
            Category // eventually this will be the selected category name
        </Button>
    </Dropdown>
)} />
```